# How to pass Dynamic Environment Variable in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, environment-variables, kubernetes-pod

I have two replica statefulset and I want to pass health URL of other pod(I mean in replica1 I want to know health URL of replica2 and vice versa), i did following

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: dapi
  labels:
    app: dapi
spec:
  serviceName: dapi
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: dapi
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: dapi
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: test-container
          image: busybox:latest
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          command: [ "sh", "-c"]
          args:
          - while true; do
              echo -en '\n';
              printenv MY_POD_NAME MASTER_HEALTH_URL;
              sleep 10;
            done;
          env:
            - name: MY_POD_NAME
              valueFrom:
                fieldRef:
                  fieldPath: metadata.name
            - name: MASTER_HEALTH_URL
              value: "http://$(MY_POD_NAME).dapi:8181/health/readiness"
```

In above code I am able to pass pod name, as its statueflset so it has predictable pod name so i tried following and its not working

```
value: "http://$(for i in 0 1; do echo dapi-$i;done | grep -v $MY_POD_NAME).dapi:8181/health/readiness"
```

So above is not working, is there any way I can pass this dynamic behavior?

PS: Above is sample manifest, for real application I don't have control on entrypoint.sh so cant over ride it.

Comment: Have you tried or considered to use Helm or Kustomize for your use case?

Comment: @WytrzymałyWiktor Not yet, but how it would support me? As Helm/Kustomize will ultimately create manifest and value for URL suppose to be decide at the time of applying manifest/creation of pod.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Could you please check the logs for the container running in your Pod when you try to use the value that does not work? What are the dependent env var values there?

Comment: Its not evaluating string and just showing value as http://$(for i in 0 1; do echo dapi-$i;done | grep -v $MY_POD_NAME).dapi:8181/health/readiness"

Comment: Does your script work when used separately?